# redirect from old to new domain, remove www and redirect to https

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to adjust htaccess so that user who are coming from my old url get redirected to the new one, also if he enters www to remove it and finally to transfer it to https://.
I was able to do this but one thing is the problem, so if user enter 
http://www.my_old_site.com/features.php which is other page on site I want to redirect him to https://my_new_site.com/features.php
What I have so far is removing www and redirecting to https://

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://%1/%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think all this can be done in one single rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my_old_site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://my_new_site.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: ok, if I type http:// my_old_site.com I've been transferred to https:// my_new_site.com which is good, however if I put http:// www.my_old_site.com I get 404.

Comment: As per these rules `http://www.my_old_site.com` should also get redirected to `http://my_new_site.com`

Comment: I have edited the code but I suspect some already existing code causing this. Can you post your latest `.htaccess` again in your question.

Comment: I have in `<ifModule>` some `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ Quester [OR]` rules, I'll try what you just sent, thanks.

Comment: Now it's bad, I'm getting repeatable paths after `.com`, lots of it and then 404 again.

Comment: Ok I rolled back that change. Do post your existing .htaccess in your question so I can investigate.

Comment: Thank you for helping. What I have in question code that's all, along with few rules which I mentioned above.

Comment: Can you comment out all of your code and keep only my suggested one for testing.

Comment: WOW, you are awesome dude. The problem was in my browser, I tried in other one and it works perfectly. Thank you so much.